# Approximate match lookup - similar text strings in Excel (No VBA & No Fuzzy Match Add-in)

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

Using Excel 2010.  I have two data sets that contain lists of employees.  The data is similar but not exact.  Need to look up if the name in data set A is in data set B.

Data Set A

```
John Smith Jr.

Dan Rogers 

Jane Doe
```

Data Set B

```
SMITH, JOHN 

ROGERS, DANIEL

DOE, JANE
```

Have tried looking up partial match formulas without luck.  Looking for a formula not using VBA or the fuzzy match excel add-in.

Thanks

Comment: This is difficult to do in any tool, but to do it in excel without VBA where you could at least do some fakey soundex, ngram, or levenshtein distance function is cuckoo bananas.

Answer (score 0):

If all your data is like the example you give, there is no need for partial match : you can directly transform your first column into the second one.

So let's assume the data set A is in column A you can just do the following :

Get First name : in column B

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)
```

Get last name : in column C

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(B1)-1),FIND(" ",A1,LEN(B1)+2)-LEN(B1)-2)
```

Then you can mimic the Dataset B format in column D

```
=UPPER(C1)&", "&UPPER(B1)
```

And just match the column D with your dataset B using a classic exact match.

I suspect your data might have middle names that will mess up with this logic, but the above will work as long as your names in data set A are all in the format

```
FirstNameinDataSetB LastNameinDataSetB AnyThingAfterDoesntMatter
```

If you need to do it in a single formula, you can compount the formulas for the steps in a single one.